# Scale codec: Is there a way to extract an enum's arm's codec index value?

Tags: rust, storage, scale-codec, serialization, scale

Using scale, an enum can be written like this:

```
#[derive(Debug, Clone, PartialEq, Eq, Encode, Decode)]
pub enum Block {
    #[codec(index = 101)]
    V1(BlockV1),
}
```

The `#[codec(index = 101)]`, the `101` part, represents the `u8` value that will be encoded in the serialization to represent the current enum arm. When this enum gets serialized, the first byte of that serialization will have the value `101`.

Given that this whole mechanism is built-in into the scale-codec, and given that making assumptions about serialization is wrong to respect encapsulation, is there a way to retrieve that `101` through a method call to the enum?

So I'm hoping for something like:

```
fn make_block() -> Block {
    // some implementation
}

fn get_that_version() -> u8 {
    let block = make_block();
    assert_eq!(block.codec_arm_index(), 101u8); // notice 101 is the same from the enum
    block.codec_arm_index()
}
```

Is such functionality available in scale?

Answer (score 2):

No there is no way to extract these information from a type. I think in your case you should just add a function to `Block` `get_version`.

Comment: The bad thing there is that I have to match inside that function and write the value twice, once in the codec parameter and once inside the `get_version` function. The `codec` parameter must be a literal, which means if I ever decide to change the encoding index for any reason (this is not specific to blocks), there will be a consistency problem that's only caught by a test that may or may not exist. I hope it's not so much trouble to add this function to scale.